# Do gziped web resources have a smaller "size" in the network inspection tool/chrome developer tools?

Tags: tomcat, iis, web, webserver, google-chrome-devtools

According to the response headers the css/js/static resources are gziped, but their actual size and fetch times have not changed from when gzip was turned off, is this to be expected?

How do I verify from the developer tools (without using the content-encoding header) that the content is actually been gziped, should the size be different?

EDIT:spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Size" column of the "Network" panel, you will also see the grayish "Content" value, which corresponds to the actual size of the resource content. If the status code is 200 and the "Content" value is considerably smaller than "Size", then the resource has been most likely compressed during the transfer. But the surefire way is checking the headers, as you have suggested.